# How cap video buffer in MediaCapture - in order to stream across a network using MediaCapture

Tags: windows, video-streaming, win-universal-app

I'm writing a simple application that needs to stream video from one PC/Phone to another, across a network.  I'm using Windows 10, this is a "Universal" application (think Skype)

**I would like the video latency to be as low as possible, even if that means dropping frames**

Feel free to tell me if I'm doing this incorrectly

1. Create a MediaCapture on the device with a camera
2. create a network connection
3. StartRecordingToStreamAsync(), using a custom
   IRandomAccessStream, which streams over the network

this is working great,  until there is a delay on the receiving end.  Everything works okay, but a latency is introduced

what is the right way to get the sending end to start dropping frames?

my technique so far is

1. introduce "flow control" on the network protocol,  such that the sending end knows how much it is ahead of the reader
2. block the writing WriteAsync() in my IRandomAccessStream until the reader catches up

**it seems that the MediaCapture object on the device with a camera has its own internal buffers,  is there a way I can specify size of the buffer it uses, along with hints as to what to do should that buffer start getting pressure?**

Comment: Did you solve it? I am having kind of the same problem: after a few seconds the capture stops without warning...